# MYSQL Group By Multiple columns - Unique listing

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a table 'table1' which has 2 columns, `flange_start` and `flange_end`. I would like a query to retreive a unique list of flanges, regardless of whether its from `_start` or `_end`.

I have tried GROUPing by `flange_start`, then `flange_end` then GROUPing the results.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My tip is UNION:

```
select distinct(flange_start) as flange from table1
union distinct
select distinct(flange_end) as flange from table1
```

and link to more reading: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html

Comment: Further to the above, if you need to be able to translate back to whether it was a start or end flange I would suggest adding a text field in for reference i.e. `SELECT DISTINCT(flange_start) AS flange, 'start' AS flange_type FROM table1` (and then of course the UNION etc)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT flange FROM 
  (SELECT flange_start as flange GROUP BY flange_start 
   UNION 
  SELECT flange_end as flange FROM table1 GROUP BY flange_end) 
GROUP BY flange
```

The idea is that you get unique flanges in the UNION then select only one of those in the outer query. It is recommended that you use GROUP BY instead of distinct as DISTINCT may not always return distinct values.

You may also need to add indexes to the flange_start and flange_end columns to improve performance.